# OpenCart - Displaying Manufacturer logos in Category page

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

OK so I want to display manufacturer logos for each category. Manufacturer logos should relate to the category i.e. the Mobile Phones category should display only those manufacturer logos which belong to the category Mobile Phones like the logo for Microsoft or Sony shouldn't be displayed here (Mobile Phones Category) but instead, it should be displayed in Gaming Consoles category.

**catalog/controller/product/category.php**

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

$this->data['manufacturers'] = array();

  $results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
       $this->data['manufacturers'][] = array(
       'manufacturer_image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'],80,80),
        'name' => $result['name'],
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
);
}
```

**category.tpl**

```
<?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_image']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Currently it shows all manufacturer logos in all categories.

Comment: you will need to filter the results from `getManufacture` by passing it a `category_id`, at the moment the function is unaware of the category context.

Comment: Just wondering why *Sony* should not be displayed within mobile phones (as we had *Sony Ericsson* up to 2012 and now it is just and only *Sony* branded)... ^_^

Comment: 1. What version of OC are You using? 2. How do You specify the relation between **category** <=> **manufacturer**? I guess You should be able to relate manufacturers to a category and then just pick up all those that are related... Or do You thing somebody could create such an intelligent algorithm that PHP will know that *Microsoft makes Xbox - let's display it on Gaming Consoles category!* ???

Answer (score 1):

OpenCart's stock manufacturer model doesn't give this sort of functionality so you'll need to create a new method. In `/catalog/model/product/manufactuer.php` add the

```
public function getManufacturersByCatgoryId($category_id) {


    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
            m.*
        FROM
            " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id)
            LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m2s.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id)
        WHERE
            p2c.category_id = '" . (int) $category_id . "'
            AND m2s.store_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'
            AND p.status = 1
            AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int) $this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'
        GROUP BY
            m.manufacturer_id
    ");

    return $query->rows;

}
```

You can then fetch it by doing this in your controller and use the code you've already got to pass it to the view:

```
$this->load->model('product/manufactuer');
$manufacturers = $this->model_product_manufacturer->getManufacturersByCategoryId($category_id);

$this->data['manufacturers'] = array();

foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
    $image = $manufacturer['image'];
    $this->data['manufacturers'][] = array(
            'manufacturer_image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'],80,80),
            'name' => $result['name'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
    );

}
```

I've not tested the above code, and you can probably optimise the SQL query a bit if you want, but it should work fine.